# ASP.NET WebForms repeater not displaying all records

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, data-access

I'm working on a legacy ASP.NET 2.0 Web Forms site. For some reason the DataReader control is not getting all the records that are pulled by the SQL Query. I run the query in SQL Management Studio and 3 records are returned. I only get 2 records when I iterate through the DataReader manually and only 2 records are displayed when I databind to a repeater.

VB.NET code:

```
sql = "SELECT tblImages.ImageID, tblProducts.ProductName FROM tblImages INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblImages.ProductID = tblProducts.ProductID WHERE tblImages.ProductID = 725 ORDER BY tblImages.Main DESC, tblImages.ImageID ASC"
comm = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
dr = comm.ExecuteReader()
If dr.Read() = True Then        
    rptGallery.DataSource = dr
    rptGallery.DataBind()
End If
dr.Close()
conn.Close()
```

Repeater Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGallery" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <li>
      <a href="getimage.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ImageID")%>&format=large" data-featherlight="image">
      <img src="getimage.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ImageID")%>&format=medium" alt="<%# Eval("ProductName")%>" /></a>
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
      </ul>
    </div>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When I do a manual iteration as in the code below I can check the variable ic and it's value after iterating through the records in the datareader is 2 when it should be 3.

```
If dr.Read() = True Then
    Dim ic As Integer = 0
    While dr.Read()
        ic = ic + 1
    End While
End If
```

Comment: ah so the statement if dr.Reader() = true is advancing the cursor by one so that skips the first record and While dr.Read() starts on record 2 instead of 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to `dr.Read()` advances the cursor. So you're skipping a record. Perhaps instead of reading the records, you should use a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.80).aspx)? Just use the `Load()` function to read the information from your data reader, then bind that to your repeater.

Also, you need to wrap your `SqlConnection` in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to make sure it gets properly disposed.

In C# it'd be like this:

```
sql = "SELECT tblImages.ImageID, tblProducts.ProductName FROM tblImages INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblImages.ProductID = tblProducts.ProductID WHERE tblImages.ProductID = 725 ORDER BY tblImages.Main DESC, tblImages.ImageID ASC";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{      
    comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);       
    conn.Open();
    dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());        
}
rptGallery.DataSource = dt;
rptGallery.DataBind();
```

In VB.NET it'd be like this (automatic code converter used as I'm not a VB coder)

```
sql = "SELECT tblImages.ImageID, tblProducts.ProductName FROM tblImages INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblImages.ProductID = tblProducts.ProductID WHERE tblImages.ProductID = 725 ORDER BY tblImages.Main DESC, tblImages.ImageID ASC"
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Using conn As New SqlConnection("connectionstring")
    comm = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)        
    conn.Open()
    dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader())       
End Using
rptGallery.DataSource = dt
rptGallery.DataBind()
```